# It's not a monad, but what is it?

Tags: haskell, monads, category-theory

[According to the Haskell wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory#Monads), a `Monad` called `m` is a `Functor` with two additional operations:

```
unit :: a -> m a
join :: m (m a) -> m a
```

That's nice, but I have something slightly different.  Glossing over the gory details, I have a type that has good `unit` and `join` functions, but its `fmap` is not well behaved (`fmap g . fmap f` is not necessarily `fmap (g.f)`).  Because of this, it cannot be made an instance of `Monad`.  Nonetheless, I'd like to give it as much generic functionality as possible.

So my question is, what category theoretic structures are similar to monads in that they have a `unit` and `join`?

I realize that on some level, the above question is ill-defined.  For monads the `unit` and `join` definitions only make sense in terms of the `fmap` definition.  Without `fmap`, you can't define any of the monad laws, so any definitions of `unit`/`join` would be equally "valid."  So I'm looking for functions other than `fmap` that it might make sense to define some "not-monad" laws on these `unit` and `join` functions.

Comment: Can you describe more about the structure you have, and what in particular causes it to fail the fusion law for `fmap`?

Comment: I suppose you specifically "tweaked" `fmap` in a way so that `join` fulfills the 2nd monad law? Normally, you almost always get `fmap g . fmap f ≡ fmap $ f.g` just automatically.

Comment: @luqui I'm more interested in general than just this specific case, but it's a normal distribution.  If you think about `fmap` as applying  a function to every point in a distribution, then `fmap` only obeys the `Functor` laws for addition and multiplication.  `unit` is training on a single data point, and `join` is merging a "normal distribution of normal distributions" into a single normal distribution.  Obviously, this requires some constraints on the parameters, so it can't be done at all using the `Base` type classes and I'be been using `ConstraintKinds` to play around with it.

Comment: Show us the code if you want an informed answer

Comment: As is well-known by now, "monads are just monoids in the category of endofunctors".  So you're looking for a `monoid`, just in a different category.  I'm not sure what category would correspond to normal distributions, but I'm a bit suspicious.  My intuition (which is frequently wrong FWIW) is that the only structure imposed by a normal distribution is isomorphic to a List.

Comment: small addendum: my previous comment is assuming that your normal distribution is parametric WRT the data.  If you restrict the allowed types such that any function `f` is monotonic, then you would have a valid (restricted) Functor and Monad.

Comment: I'm trying to stay away from the specific example of a normal distribution, and just trying to understand the basic concept.  I had forgotten that `unit`/`join` define a monoid, and I just have to think of different categories.  I think this is the intuition I was looking for.

Comment: @JohnL: that would probably be the category of affine spaces (over R?).

Comment: Your normal-distribution application sounds quite similar to what I tried as [an uncertainty-propagation type](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/uncertainly-haskell/blob/master/Data/Uncertain.hs). I think I checked it does obey the functor law, if you obtain the result width with differentiation laws! Certainly when the distribution widths remain small enough that you can neglect higher-order Taylor summands; otherwise the whole approach doesn't seem very useful anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well here's one law you should have with just `unit` and `join`. Given `x :: m a`,

```
join (unit x) = x
```

---

To show that this didn't just come from nowhere, let's start with an existing monad law:

```
return x >>= f = f x
```

Given that `m >>= f = join (fmap f m)`

```
join (fmap f (return x)) = f x
```

Select `f = id`

```
join (fmap id (return x)) = id x
```

Use the functor law that `fmap id = id`

```
join (id (return x)) = id x
```

Use the obvious `id a = a`

```
join (return x) = x
```